# When to call _pclose?

Tags: c, windows, pipe, popen, pclose

I have a function in which I call _open a few times.

If `_popen` returns `NULL` do I need to call `_pclose` before the function returns?

I've marked 3 locations where I think `_pclose` might need to be called.

At which of these locations must I call `_pclose`?

```
bool theFunction()
{
    FILE* pPipe;
    char buffer[1000];
    if( (pPipe = _popen("dir", "rt")) == NULL )
    {
        //location 1
        _pclose(pPipe);
        return false;
    }

    while(fgets(pipeBuffer, maxBufferSize, pPipe))
    {
        printf(pipeBuffer);
    }

    if( (pPipe = _popen("cls", "rt")) == NULL )
    {
        //location 2
        _pclose(pPipe);
        return false;
    }

    //location 3
    _pclose(pPipe);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You cannot close anything you were not able to open. Look at your first example, you are trying to close `NULL`.

Comment: Think about it from `_pclose()`'s perspective... if you passed it `NULL`, how could it know what to close anyway?

Comment: Ok, sorry if it seemed like a poor questions.  While I understood pPipe is `Null` at those points, I'm new to pipes and these commands.  I asked because I wanted to make sure there was not something else being cleaned up in `_pclose`.  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Did you look up the man page? Here is [the Windows page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25xdhsd2.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I had already read the man page.

Comment: What do you think `_pclose(NULL)` does exactly?

Comment: I didn't know exactly what `_pclose` does.  That's why I asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: close the pipe if you could open it but no longer need it. So:

```
bool theFunction()
{
    FILE* pPipe;
    char buffer[1000];
    if( (pPipe = _popen("dir", "rt")) == NULL )
    {
        return false;
    }

    while(fgets(pipeBuffer, maxBufferSize, pPipe))
    {
        printf(pipeBuffer);
    }

    // The fact that you have to close it here in the middle of nowhere
    // should ring a bell that you need to think about separation of concern 
    _pclose(pPipe);

    if( (pPipe = _popen("cls", "rt")) == NULL )
    {
        return false;
    }

    _pclose(pPipe);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why did you place your first call to `_pclose` where you did?

Comment: Because you're overwriting `pPipe` after that, so you lose the value of the first pipe and you can't close it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you successfully create a pipe with `popen` but do not call `pclose`, then the memory occupied by the `FILE` object is not released. Worse, there are externally visible consequences. The child process which was created by `popen` may linger around. When you `popen`, a process is created with `fork`. The corresponding `waitpid` might not happen until `pclose` is called. (I believe that that is a typical, obvious implementation, and it is how I have implemented popen-like functions for other programming languages.)

Although Win32 doesn't have `fork` and `wait`, there is likely a similar resource issue in Microsoft C Library's `_popen`.  The `FILE` pipe handle probably has an internal Win32 handle to a process, which is not subject to a `CloseHandle` until `_pclose` is invoked. Plus other resources like Win32 pipes which communicate with that process. If you don't close the pipe, then you leak these resources.

About passing a null pointer. This is a no-no with the original POSIX function. The behavior is not defined if `pclose` is invoked on a null pointer. POSIX says that *"[i]f the argument stream to pclose() is not a pointer to a stream created by popen(), the result of pclose() is undefined."*  (A null pointer isn't a pointer to a stream, even if it was returned by `popen`).

Microsoft allows `_pclose` to be called with a null pointer. This is [documented in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25xdhsd2.aspx) and the behavior is that `_pclose` returns -1 and sets the `errno` pseudo-variable to `EINVAL`.

That's something to consider if you ever want to port code that is based on these functions.